# Use a variable in a postgresql execute statement

Tags: postgresql, dynamic, plpgsql

I am trying to have a parameter when creating a trigger function.

I have been trying to use this code:

```sql
DO $DO$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format($TRIGGER$
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.my_trigger_fcn() RETURNS trigger AS
  $BODY$
    DECLARE
      my_geom geometry(MultiPoint,%1$s);
    BEGIN
      my_geom = st_collect(NEW.situation_geometry)::geometry(MultiPoint,%$1s);
      NEW.geometry = my_geom;
      RETURN NEW;
    END;
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
$TRIGGER$, :SRID);
END
$DO$;
```

and trying to run this code with `psql -v SRID=2056 -f myfile`.
But I get a syntax error.

I have also tried the SQL [execute](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-execute.html) command, but prepared statements are [not allowed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html) to create trigger function.

Any idea?

---

**SOLUTION**:

Thanks to @Pavel Stehule, here is the code that works:

```sql
SELECT set_config('my.srid', :SRID::text, false);
DO $DO$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format($TRIGGER$
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION qgep_od.my_trigger_fcn() RETURNS trigger AS
  $BODY$
    DECLARE
      my_geom geometry(MultiPoint,%1$s);
    BEGIN
      my_geom = st_collect(NEW.situation_geometry)::geometry(MultiPoint,%1$s);
      NEW.geometry = my_geom;
      RETURN NEW;
    END;
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
$TRIGGER$, current_setting('my.srid'));
END
$DO$;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot to use psql variables inside any SQL string. The string is body of `DO` command too. You can use session variables:

```
\set myvar xxx
select set_config('my.myvar', :'myvar', false); 
do $$
begin
  execute format('create or replace function fx() returns void as $_$begin raise notice %L; end$_$ language plpgsql', current_setting('my.myvar')); 
end;
$$;

postgres=# \sf fx
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fx()
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$begin raise notice 'xxx'; end$function$
```

Other possibility is do this replacement before psql - you can use `sed`